# Django : One to Many serializer attribute error

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Hello i have one to many model serializer but when I try to make request on it it says attribute error.

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `project` on serializer `clientserializers`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Client` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Client' object has no attribute 'projectname'
```

This is how i execute on views

```
jsonified_client = client_serialize.clientserializers(client_list, many=True)
json_data = JSONRenderer().render(jsonified_client.data)
return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

My model :

```
# client structure
class Project(db.Model):
    project_name = db.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name


class Reason(db.Model):
    reason_name = db.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.reason_name


class Client(db.Model):
    name = db.CharField(max_length=100)
    project = db.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=db.CASCADE, related_name="projectname")
    reason = db.ForeignKey(Reason, on_delete=db.CASCADE, related_name="reasonname")
    timestamp = db.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
```

Serializer both for project and reason:

```
class projectserializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields =('id', 'project_name')
class reasonserializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Reason
        fields =('id', 'reason_name')

class clientserializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    project = projectserializers(source="projectname", many=True)
    reason = reasonserializers(source="reasonname", many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'timestamp', 'project', 'reason')
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `source` and `many` argument values -

```py
class clientserializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    project = projectserializers()
    reason = reasonserializers()
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'timestamp', 'project', 'reason')
```

---

As per the [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names) standards, class names should normally use the ***CapWords*** convention.

So, `projectserializers` should be `Projectserializers` (or `ProjectSerializers`) and `reasonserializers` should be `Reasonserializers` (or `ReasonSerializers`)

Comment: I tried but it says  `'Project' is not iterable`

Comment: Remove `many=True` also.